# How can I configure openldap on multihomed clients

Tags: linux, centos6, openldap

I have OpenLDAP on a server with 2 separated nics connecting to an LDAP server.  If I unplug nic1 cable, I cannot get LDAP to authenticate via nic2.  Is there a way to make nic2 work with LDAP authentication? Looks like by default, nic1 ipaddress is connected to LDAP Server on port 389.  Can I have both ipaddresses connect to LDAP server?

Comment: If you unplug one the routing tables will need adjusting, or maybe they already do. Off topic.

Answer (score 0):

By default OpenLDAP will listen on all addresses, ref: http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/security.html

It sounds to me like this is a problem with your HA network configuration, not OpenLDAP.  Does the host have network connectivity at all after unplug the first NIC?

Comment: I have ip rule to direct traffic so that the 2 nics have their own traffic.  When first NIC is unplugged, NIC2 can still send and receive data.  When I do netstat, only nic1 is connected to ldap server.  So I figured if I have another instance of ldap client running with source IP of NIC2, then that might work when NIC1 is out.

Comment: Is the server you are unplugging the NIC from the client or the server?
 Can you update your post with the relevant netstat output both before and after you unplug the NIC?  I'm trying to determine if you are referring to the server listening or an active socket.  Most LDAP queries are stateless like HTTP, I'm wondering if you have some persistent session for replication or monitoring.

Comment: there's nslcd running on the client to connect to ldap. Before unplugging NIC1 on client: tcp        0      0 172.16.0.166:33066          172.22.0.16:389             ESTABLISHED 1928/nslcd

Comment: after: tcp        0      1 172.16.0.166:37214          172.22.0.16:389             SYN_SENT    1928/nslcd
tcp        0    229 172.16.0.166:33066          172.22.0.16:389             ESTABLISHED 1928/nslcd
tcp        0      0 172.16.0.166:33064          172.22.0.16:389             ESTABLISHED 1928/nslcd
tcp        0    341 172.16.0.166:33056          172.22.0.16:389             FIN_WAIT1   -
tcp        0    341 172.16.0.166:33060          172.22.0.16:389             FIN_WAIT1   -
tcp        0      0 172.16.0.166:33058          172.22.0.16:389             ESTABLISHED 1928/nslcd

Comment: IP rule is such that what comes in on eth0 goes out on eth0, and same as eth1: from 172.16.0.166/32 table eth0table
to 172.16.0.166/32 table eth0table

Comment: Does 172.16.0.166 move from NIC1 -> NIC2 when NIC 1 goes down? Have you looked into bonding?  https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/bonding